# Unable to set custom field value in lightning record edit form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-combobox

I have a button that creates a new case. There are different record types for Case Object and I need to create a record for a specific record type only. I am using lightning-record-edit form to capture the data. There's a lookup on Field_1 and a lookup on Field_2. Field_2 is child of Field_1. When a select Field_1, I need to get the children and display them as the only option in Field_2.

When I am saving the form I am getting the following error:

```
A component Error has occurred!
Mesasge: [Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Field_2__c)]
```

HTML

```
<template}>
  <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" record-type-id={recordTypeId} onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Field_1__c" value={field1Value} onchange={handleField1Change}></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-combobox name="Field_2" label="Field 2" value={field2Value} onchange={handleField2Change} options={field2Options}></lightning-combobox>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Field_2__c" value={field2Value} class="slds-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS

```
@track field1Value;
@track field2Value;
@track field2Options = [];

@track recordTypeId = '012000000000000AAA';

handleField1Change(event) {
    this.field1Value = event.detail.value;
    this.field2Options = [];
    getChild({ parentId: this.field1Value })
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            for (let i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                this.field2Options = [...this.field2Options, {value: result[i].Id, label: result[i].Name}];
            }
        }
        if (result.length === 1) {
            this.field2Value = this.field2Options[0].value;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
         console.log('error fetching children: ', error)
    });
}

handleField2Change(event) {
    this.field2Value = event.detail.value;
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    fields.Field_2__c = this.field2Value;
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}
```

Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Field_2__c> getChild(Id parentId) {
    return [SELECT Name FROM Field_2__c WHERE Field_1__c =: parentId];
}
```

PS: When I remove `fields.Field_2__c = this.field2Value` from the `handleSubmit()` method, the record gets saved but the `Field_2__c` field does not gets saved. Only the `Field_1__c` value gets saved. But in the UI the value is reflected and also when I console log the `field2Value`, I can see the value (ID of the child component).